# "Ask Question" similar questions workflow

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

I wonder if this would be possible using the data that SO produces. There is a common C# question "null reference exception" (with various flavours etc). Someone created a lovely answer to cover this and nowadays the answer is almost always closed off as a duplicate manually.

When asking a question, the "Questions that may already have your answer" section is useful and people need to make more use of it. However, this clearly is ignored or disregarded with at least a decent frequency on the question I use as an example above.

My questions are:

1. Using title content, question content, tagging, and the "Questions that may already have your answer" section, can we determine if a question has a high likelihood of closure because of duplication?
2. If so, say a question achieves a "this is 80% likely to be a duplicate", instead of offering a list of links to questions that may contain the answer, could we push the user down a forced track of reading 1-3 questions before being allowed to post it? This information can be encoded into the question so the community doesn't just then close it off without first seeing what they went through.

The "forced questions to read" could be weighted based on the question that gets targeted as the duplicate for the relevant question, or upvotes on answers, quantity of answers / discussion etc.

A mitigating factor was the change to allow gold badge people to close off duplicates - this helps.

Curiosity causes me to ask if data mining could allow a slight advancement in the automation of duplicate detection before it falls back onto the community to do the clean-up.

**Update 1:**

Lattyware had a good suggestion:

> If there is a really high match, we present the best match as 'Your
>   question has already been answered, here it is!', and then give it.
>   Below that there can be a 'This hasn't answered my question.' which
>   removes the auto-dupe. That way it's shown as a fast track as opposed
>   to a barrier, making it far less likely the user just skips by it.

The idea remains the same: the necessary backing metrics to be able to produce a confidence value on the question you present or the wording you use ("Your question has been answered!" vs "Your question seems very similar to this one, please take a look.").

**Update 2:**

l4mpi raises good points about how this aims to improve on the status quo. I think the take away from the discussion is that we don't understand the reasoning behind a user posting a duplicate even though SO already presents a comprehensive and nicely formatted list of similar questions:

- Did they see it and deliberately ignore it?
- Did they even see it? Not many standard forum sites have this feature.
- Did they see it and disregard it because they assume their question is unique in their context?
- Did they not want to leave the "Ask Question" workflow to read the questions for fear of losing their question content?
- Did they not want to spend the time reading answers that may have no relevance?

Comment: So, how would you make sure the people actually _read_ the questions and not just open them in a new tab and then proceed to post their own question? I think the only use of that feature would be annoying people who ask duplicate questions, which may have a postivie side effect but probably isn't worth the effort.

Comment: @l4mpi You wouldn't. The automation would fail or the user would be discouraged (possible negative side-effect), the duplicate would be created and the community would then react: close the duplicate as a duplicate of a question they apparently read. The asker then replies if their situation is different and hopefully improves the question; it gets optionally re-opened.

Comment: @l4mpi It's always fun to annoy people who waste my time. =D

Comment: I think the best option might be to present this a different way. If there is a really high match, we present the best match as 'Your question has already been answered, here it is!', and then give it. Below that there can be a 'This hasn't answered my question.' which removes the auto-dupe. That way it's shown as a fast track as opposed to a barrier, making it far less likely the user just skips by it.

Comment: @Lattyware I like that change. Perhaps the workflow can be to change the "ask my question" button to "We think it is answered here, take a look", they look and on the page below the most likely answer is "sorry, that didn't answer my question", "ok, ask it".

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth but in that case, how is your proposed workflow any better than the status quo? People already don't read the duplicates, forcing them won't make a difference.

Comment: @l4mpi Who knows? There are no metrics available that state how many people willingly ignore those questions, those who believe their question is unique regardless because they are in their own context, or those who simply don't see them because not many sites offer that feature. Without those metrics, we simply have assumptions. I prefer to test assumptions so unless the workflow is changed and the affect recorded, we remain unable to reach a conclusion to your point.

Comment: I think the issue might be the OP seeing a *similar* question and not a *duplicate* question, when we see a *duplicate*.  Many inexperienced users come and expect customized solutions to their specific question, rather than learning to think about the problem itself and how to apply new knowledge to solving it.  While some people have a knack for it, real problem solving is a learned skill.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Interesting. Something as simple as a wording change can change the perception just enough to have a positive impact. Talk about low hanging fruit! I wonder how much it costs to change a sentence on SO :-)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I think it goes beyond a wording change - you may have misunderstood - I literally mean... the user reads the question says "sure this is very similar to my problem but it doesn't help me exactly" , where the question is truly a duplicate with just a slightly different context.  I think `LINQ` questions suffer from this problem because there are so many variables.  No 2 questions are exactly alike, but many about the same things and are probably duplicates.  New users are used to forums where you are often given customized solutions and not forced to think for yourself.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Sorry yes I didn't catch that part of your meaning. Unfortunately, I don't see what SO directly can do to stop people having that approach.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth you are right - there's not much we can do, but it could be a possible hitch in your idea.  But I do like the premise.

Answer (score 2):

I think psubsee2003 has a good point, I think less experienced programmers such as myself have a hard time generalizing from analogous questions and coming up with the right question. This is an inherent part of being new at anything.

I would suggest a more radical change. Instead of closing question that are similar, I would suggest a more dynamic approach that will lead to better questions and answers, so that people would not seem to ignore the previously asked questions.

If a question is flagged as a duplicate, present the duplicator with the original question and ask why they asked the duplicate that question. If they respond they didn't find it, redirect questions worded similarly to how they asked the question to the original question. If they didn't understand how it was relevant or if they feel that there are nuances that are different and important have them state this, then present this to the people who flagged it as a duplicate. At this point the people who flagged it should review the response and decide if the two answers should be merged or not. If they decide it should be merged send the work to the crowd, and let people like me (people who are desperate to get more points on stack overflow) to try add to the existing answer so that these nuances are included. Otherwise delete the duplicate.

This is just a ruff work flow, the key point is that the existing question shouldn't be static, but should be improved upon thus addressing the reason (if there is one) that a similar question was asked.